# Isit possible to get card info when creating Stripe 3ds source?

Tags: stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I notice that when I create a 3ds source and when creating a charge object using this source, I cannot get any card info like the last 4 digits?

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to access this information on the charge unfortunately. You have to look at the Source type and if it's `three_d_secure` you need to look at `source[three_d_secure][card]` and then use this id which will be for the Card Source and retrieve it [via the API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_source) to find the relevant card information such as last 4 digits.